# heightForRowAtIndexPath - how to default to maximum element height of cell

Tags: ios, tableview

I have been developing a couple of tableviews now. I feel like wasting time implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` all the time. Is there some way to default the height to the maximum element `y` value of the row, which is obviously constructed from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` adding a default padding?

I am asking myself, why this method is not in the default iOS and developers may override this method, if the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is too memory consuming.

Comment: As you said, creating *all* table view cells can be a time and memory expensive operation, so I can understand that this is not the default method. But we can only speculate why Apple does or doesn't implement something ...

Answer (score 0):

The following code show how we implement our call to -`heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

  CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

  return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i am doing. and i hate doing this. there must be something more clever.